# Are GraphFrames compatible with typed Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

We currently use typed Dataset in our work. And we are currently exploring using Graphframes.

However, Graphframes seem to be based on Dataframe which is Dataset[Row]. Would Graphframes be compatible with typed Dataset. e.g. Dataset[Person]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GrahpFrames` support only `DataFrames`. To use statically `Dataset` you have convert it to `DataFrame`, apply graph operations, and convert back to statically structure.

You can follow this issue: https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/133